# Does Gson’s fromJSON have a parsing limit on the string parameter?

Tags: java, json, gson

I’m using GSON to convert a JSON string stored in our DB to our corresponding object class.

```
String configData = dbCall.fetchPublishedData(dbURL); //returns JSON string
Gson gson = new Gson();
publishDataObject = gson.fromJson(configData, PublishedDataVO.class);
```

For the most part, this is working, except for one particular row in our DB that is failing with an exception from the GSON parser.  All of our rows in the DB are created with the same tool and have the same data structure, the only difference for this one row is that it holds A LOT of data in its JSON string.  When I try to retrieve this data and transform it into our class object, I am getting the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated string at line 1 column 4001 path...
```

The size of the data string in this row is the only difference with the other row's strings.  I even took the JSON string and formatted it to see if it is a valid JSON string, and it doesn't show errors.  Does GSON have a limit on the input string size for its `fromJSON` method?

Comment: Maybe the column size in the DB is `4000` and the data is truncated.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I thought so too, but calling the stored procedure that fetches the data returns the whole thing...unless there's some issue with truncation of data from the Java controller to the DB

Comment: Did you confirm using jsonlint?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yeah, the data in the table is valid JSON

Comment: https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/Gson.java - I suggest that you just try stepping into the code using a debugger.

Comment: Did you solve this?